# MahApps WPF Flyout Zindex control

Tags: .net, wpf, frameworks

I seem to be encountering a problem when trying to apply Z-index property to my XAML. What I am trying to achieve is to have a control within my first border->grid to go on top of the MahApps flyout. My problem is, Panel.ZIndex doesn't seem to work for MahApps MetroWindow.Flyouts. I can't bring the ZIndex of my control to the top. Any clue how I can approach this?

```
<Border>
    <Grid>
        <Control (Control I want to bring to the top)>
            ...
        </Control>
        <ContentControl>
            ...
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Border>

<metro:MetroWindow.Flyouts (I want to bring behind my control)>
    <metro:FlyoutsControl>
        <metro:Flyout IsOpen="{Binding MenuManager.IsCharmMenuOpen}" Position="Right" Width="85" Header="Menu">
        ...
        </metro:Flyout>
    </metro:FlyoutsControl>
</metro:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZIndex is only used to order direct children in a panel, not the children's children. The control you are trying to bring to the top is on a different level in the `VisualTree` than the Flyouts, so unless you bring the whole `Border` on top, you can't bring only the `Control` you want on top.